# How to combine background images?

Tags: css, image, background, sprite

I have some pictures I am using on my website. I am trying to reduce the http requests. In my header I have my logo floated left and then another picture with special offers etc floated to the right in the same div. My question how do I combine these together and still work out the amount of space I need between them as I am using a fluid layout.
Would you also advise combining the main background image with these logos etc and if yes how do i do this so it still looks correct in a a fluid layout

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients

Comment: I think it is more related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906413/css-advantages-of-single-image-file-vs-multiple-files